# It is possible to configure Storage Manager(SM) and Archive directory location of SM in different machines?

Tags: amazon-s3, nuodb

Installed NuoDB 3.0 Linux version in one machine and while creating database it is possible to give archive directory location is Amazon s3 buckets storage ?

Here SM is running on one machine and archive location is pointing to Amazon s3 buckets(Storage area). i.e (Archive directory is different machine).

If it is possible please share the information how to follow the process.

Answer (score 0):

The archive directory must be a valid location in the file system of the machine it runs on. You'll have mount S3 on the machine on which the SM is running

Comment: I have SM running on CentOS machine and have another file system location (Ceph) with S3 API configured. 
Do you have an idea as how to configure or locate the S3 API inside SM configuration? How do we pass on security info so that S3 allows to receive the request?
I have used the command as below but it didn't work out and didn't receive any error message also:
start process sm archive myBucket.storage.myDomain.io host localhost database myDatabase initialize true